# how to break a line after matching a certain character using shell command?

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, cut

File1:

```
John Daniel Hommes Cameron;Emily Terry Mussy Barbara
Mimi Papu;David Swiss Jen
Hans Peter Iril;Kelvin
Lilly Gucci Kate Nik;Forum Bill
June;Jill and Jack
```

Output file:

```
John Daniel Hommes Cameron
Emily Terry Mussy Barbara
Mimi Papu
David Swiss Jen
Hans Peter Iril
Kelvin
Lilly Gucci Kate Nik
Forum Bill
June
Jill and Jack
```

Comment: It looks like you want to replace each `;` with a newline so: `tr \; \\n <infile`

Comment: @don_crissti - did we post here at the same time? i only now noticed your comment. you're a smart guy. i know that because... so am i.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tr \; \\n <in >out
```

...is very likely the most efficient means of going from your sample input to your sample output.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you want to replace every instance of `;` with a newline. You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's,;,\n,g' <FILE>
```

If your `sed` does not support `-i`:

```
sed  's,;,\n,g' <FILE>  > <OUTPUT_FILE>
```

Comment: its giving me an error, --i illegal option. @arkadiusz

Comment: First, try with a single dash: `-i`. If it doesn't work you probably use non-GNU `sed`.

Comment: uea I am using non-GNU sed... I have used single dash -i

Comment: @Nainita: edited

Comment: `<in> > <out>` is at least a *little* ambiguous. Maybe you could phrase that better? Also, the `\n` escape used on the `s///`ubstitution's right-hand-side is just as likely *(if not more)* to cause portability problems with various `sed`s than is `-i`. @Nainita - since you want to convert - or *`tr`anslate* - all occurrences of one character into an equal number of occurrences of another, you should avoid all `s///`-type regexps if possible. `sed`'s translation function is `y` - and you *can* portably use the `\n` escape w/ it: `y/;/\n/` - but just `tr \; \\n <i >o` is both easier and faster.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes.... its working now.... thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}{print $0}' filename
```

Comment: Shorter version: `awk -v RS=\; 1 File1`